# Kotlin transform element with values from previous item in collection

Tags: kotlin, collections

I have a list of objects of type `MyObject`:

```
data class MyObject(val name: String?, val age: Int)
```

I want to go through the list, and for those values with `name == null`, I'd like to copy the value on the previous item, if present. And if possible id like to carry the changes over, so if item 0 has name, 1 doesnt, and 2 doesnt; 1 should get name from 0, and 2 should get name from 1 which got its name from 0.

I hope this makes sense.

I sense this is something there might be a builtin function for like reduce, scan or something similar but I cant seem to get to the solution?

Example input:

```
[ MyObject("Paul", 21),
MyObject(null, 23),
MyObject(null, 17),
MyObject("Mike", 45),
MyObject("Laura", 20),
MyObject(null, 60)
]
```

Example output:

```
[ MyObject("Paul", 21),
MyObject("Paul", 23),
MyObject("Paul", 17),
MyObject("Mike", 45),
MyObject("Laura", 20),
MyObject("Laura", 60)
]
```

Comment: Can you show some examples of the inputs and outputs?

Comment: What if the *first* item has a null name?

Comment: @Sweeper just did, if the first is null then its just null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there is a built-in [`scan`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/scan.html) (aka [`runningFold`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/running-fold.html)), it is more appropriate to use [`runningReduce`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/running-reduce.html) (as suggested by [lukas.j](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17218429/lukas-j)) here, since you do not need to use a dummy object as the initial value.

```
val result = list.runningReduce() { acc, obj ->
    MyObject(obj.name ?: acc.name, obj.age)
}
```

This creates a new list with new `MyObject` instances.

You can also [`fold`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/fold.html) with a mutable list:

```
val result = list.fold(mutableListOf<MyObject>()) { list, obj ->
    list.apply {
        val name = obj.name ?: lastOrNull()?.name
        add(MyObject(name, obj.age))
    }
}
```

The idea is to use the name of the object last added to the list, if `obj.name` is null.

Alternatively, if you want to mutate the `MyObject`s in place, you should make `name` a `var`:

```
data class MyObject(var name: String?, val age: Int)
```

and use [`zipWithNext`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/zip-with-next.html):

```
list.zipWithNext { prev, curr ->
    if (curr.name == null) {
        curr.name = prev.name
    }
    // shorter but less readable IMO:
    //curr.name = curr.name ?: prev.name
}
```

Comment: runningReduce would work the same and would be shorter than runningFold, as one does not need an initial object and does not have to drop it later. Of course only if the first element has a name which is not null.

Comment: Basically:  _...= list.runningReduce { acc, obj -> obj.copy(name = obj.name ?: acc.name) }_

Comment: @lukas.j Thanks! I got distracted by OP's line about finding a `scan` function. :)

Comment: Maybe _obj.copy(name = obj.name ?: acc.name)_ might be better than using the main constructor of MyObject. Depends on ones taste in the end.

Comment: @lukas.j yeah. I don't like to do it for just two parameters. The code feels just about as long.

Answer (score 0):

```kotlin
data class MyObject(var name: String?, val age: Int) // you need to make name reassignable by declaring it with var

fun setNames(list: MutableList<MyObject>) {
    list.withIndex().forEach { elementWithIndex ->
        if (elementWithIndex.value.name == null && elementWithIndex.index != 0) {
            elementWithIndex.value.name = list[elementWithIndex.index - 1].name
        }
    }
}
```